# Can I use 'let' in jsx syntax?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsx, let

I've tried to create some variables using es6 let in jsx syntax, but firefox gave me an error...

I haven't problems when I using var

Can I use let in jsx syntax and if it's impossible, can you explain me why?

Comment: `let` has nothing to do with JSX. If your browser supports `let` you can use it. Since you don't provide any information there isn't really anything else we can do to help you fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I use 'let' in jsx syntax?

Yes. JSX is merely an *extension* of the JavaScript syntax, so any valid JavaScript syntax can be used with JSX ([small example using the babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=%2F%2F%20React%20placeholder%0Alet%20React%20%3D%20%7BcreateElement()%20%7B%7D%7D%3B%0Afunction%20Link()%20%7B%7D%0A%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%2042%3B%0A%3CLink%20key%3D%7Bindex%7D%20%2F%3E%3B&playground=true)).

Of course you have to convert JSX to JavaScript before you can run the code in a JS engine and the engine has to support the features you want to use (such as `let`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply